# Using result of one query to input as variable to other queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-cursor

I've implemented this is in Python, but I am hoping there is a faster way of doing it in MySQL natively.

I have a table called allNames.  I would like to take the result of a `select` query on this table and pass each row as a variable to another query (which is also a `select`).

In Python, it looks like this:

```
def getOccurancePerVending_Count(cur):
    try:
        cur.execute(qur.allNames)
        allNames =cur.fetchall()
        for n in allNames:
            cur.execute(qur.nameVend%(n[0]))
            count = cur.fetchone()
            print("%s,%s"%(n[0],count)
    except:
        print("Didn't work")
```

This works with python, but it is incredibly slow ofr a very large database. I'm hopnig that doing it in MySQL  is much faster.

EDIT: added MYSQL attempt at doign this in MySQL...

```
drop procedure if exists GetFilteredData;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFilteredData()
BEGIN

    DECLARE bDone INT;
    DECLARE f_name varchar(150);

    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR select fname from allNames;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

    OPEN curs;

    SET bDone = 0;   
    repeat
        SET @sql = concat('select distinct(vend) from nameVend where fName =(', f_name,')');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    until bDone END REPEAT;

    close curs;
END$$
call GetFilteredData()
```

Comment: Perhaps use a join? Showing the queries and schema would help.

Comment: If you're every doing SQL in a loop there is usually a better SQL way. And really show the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`.

Comment: You are really cutting down on the number of people who can answer this to those who are python aware.

Comment: @P.Salmon added a attempt at doing this in MySQL to try and increase my answer pool.

Comment: You have defined the cursor but you are not reading from it so you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the sql way of doing things you possibly just need

```
select distinct(vend) 
from allNames a
join nameVend b on a.<fieldname> = b.<fieldname>;
```

And you don't need a procedure. Adding table defintions, sample data and expected output would help clarify.